# Use Column Header Name Within Index-Match Function VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to modify my Index-Match function to use the column header names defined in row 1, rather than the column letters.

The function resides in a sheet named *AssetName Sheet* and references a sheet named *AMP Sheet*

[image]

Here is my code for the Index-Match:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('AMP Sheet'!$L:$L,MATCH("*"&B2&"*", 'AMP Sheet'!$B:$B,0)), "")
```

***'AMP Sheet' !$L:$L* - This is referring to column L in the AMP Sheet tab. I want to replace using column letter L in the formula with its column name *ID***

[image]

***'AMP Sheet' !$B:$B* - This is referring to column B in the AMP Sheet tab. I want to replace using column letter B in the formula with its column name *Name***

[image]

*"&B2&"* - This part of the function does not need to change! The function is within a sheet tab named *AssetName Sheet* which columns will not change. This will stay as-is.

Thank you!

Comment: Just use `MATCH` to return the column value, then offset column A:A by that value -1. So something like: `INDEX(OFFSET(A:A,,MATCH("ID",1:1,0)-1),1)`

Comment: @Tragamor thank you, but not really sure how this would help with my current formula (which is using 2 sheets)

Comment: You would just qualify the sheets within the formula to get for example `OFFSET('AMP Sheet'!$A:$A,,MATCH("ID",'AMP Sheet'!1:1,0)-1)` and `OFFSET('AMP Sheet'!$A:$A,,MATCH("Name",'AMP Sheet'!1:1,0)-1)`

Comment: @Tragamor Thank you, this is helpful. Now, I'm just having a hard time incorporating that with my formula.

Comment: You should be able to just replace `'AMP Sheet'!$L:$L` and `'AMP Sheet'!$B:$B` with the two formulae above

Comment: Try `=IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET('AMP Sheet'!$A:$A,,MATCH("ID",'AMP Sheet'!1:1,0)-1),MATCH("*"&B2&"*",OFFSET('AMP Sheet'!$A:$A,,MATCH("Name",'AMP Sheet'!1:1,0)-1),0)),"")
`.

Comment: Thank you. Now, the issue is when trying to fill down the formula, it changes the 1:1 to 2:2, 3:3, etc. and does not work. Is there any way I can keep the 1:1 value static when performing a fill-down?

Comment: Oh wait, got it. Just added $1:$1

Comment: Thank you! It's working great now! :)

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, both Tragamor and VBasic2008 came up with a working solution. Here it is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET('AMP Sheet'!$A:$A,,MATCH("ID",'AMP Sheet'!$1:$1,0)-1),MATCH("*"&B1&"*",OFFSET('AMP Sheet'!$A:$A,,MATCH("Name",'AMP Sheet'!$1:$1,0)-1),0)),"")
```